# scriptaculous and JQuery do not collaborate

Tags: jquery, scriptaculous

I am using jQuery slider to browse images and Scriptaculous slider animation on the same page. They work perfectly if I put in two separate pages.

When I order the code in this way.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/prototype.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/scriptaculous.js?load=effects"></script>               
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/lightbox.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/coda-slider-2.0/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/coda-slider-2.0/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/coda-slider-2.0/jquery.coda-slider-2.0.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){      
        jQuery('#coda-slider-1').codaSlider({
        dynamicArrows: false,
        dynamicTabs: false
    });
    });            
</script>
```

Scriptaculous slide is working and jQuery slide stops working.
When I order this way.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/coda-slider-2.0/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/coda-slider-2.0/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/coda-slider-2.0/jquery.coda-slider-2.0.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){      
        jQuery('#coda-slider-1').codaSlider({
        dynamicArrows: false,
        dynamicTabs: false
    });
    });            
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/prototype.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/scriptaculous.js?load=effects"></script>               
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/lightbox.js"></script>
```

jQuery starts working and Scriptaculous slide stops working.
Then I looked for some solution around and it is stated that using jQuery.noConflict(); and replacing selector $ with jQuery can solve the problem but it doesn't. I put these two things in the code and try this way.

```
script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/prototype.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/scriptaculous.js?load=effects"></script>               
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/lightbox.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/coda-slider-2.0/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/coda-slider-2.0/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/coda-slider-2.0/jquery.coda-slider-2.0.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){      
        jQuery('#coda-slider-1').codaSlider({
        dynamicArrows: false,
        dynamicTabs: false
    });
    });            
</script>
```

That only forces jQuery to work no matter what order it and it makes Scriptaculous stop working.

Any suggestion is appreciated here. Cheers.

Comment: Does the slider plugin behave in terms of using `$`?

Comment: Good point. I'd try doing a search-and-replace on that plugin if it does. Do you get any errors?

Comment: Nope. I have already replaced all "$" with "jQuery".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not so well versed with Scriptaculous, but just two things right off the bat:

1. If you're planning to use jQuery with another library (then call `.noConflict()`), **load jQuery first**, then call `.noConflict()`, *then* load the other libraries. In this case, prototype and scriptaculous. Safer that way, if I'm not mistaken.
2. Make sure that the jQuery coda slider plugin actually supports `.noConflict()`. I think this is what Derek above was trying to say --- once you've called `.noConflict()`, jQuery releases the `$` variable back into the open (for scriptaculous to use, for example). If the coda slider uses the `$` variable heavily (without adapting to `.noConflict()`), that could be a big problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're not likely to get this working—Scriptaculous depends on Prototype to do it's thing.

Your best option is to find a jQuery-compatible replacement for the Scriptaculous effect that you're using.

Comment: I can't find similar feature for Scriptaculous thumbmail sliders which slide 20 images in a box with the width for 5 images.

Comment: I think this one look cool but requires some changes to meet my requirements. Thanks Dan. http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/svwt/

Answer (score 1):

jquery.coda-slider-2.0.js depends on `$`, you'll need to update any references to `$` in that file to be `jQuery`, and continue using noConflict()

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/coda-slider-2.0/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/coda-slider-2.0/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/coda-slider-2.0/jquery.coda-slider-2.0.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){      
        jQuery('#coda-slider-1').codaSlider({
        dynamicArrows: false,
        dynamicTabs: false
    });
    });            
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/prototype.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/scriptaculous.js?load=effects"></script>               
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/lightbox.js"></script>
```

With [this file](http://jsfiddle.net/pQzuA/1/) for jquery.coda-slider-2.0.js

If this doesn't work, you'll probably want to either scrap jQuery and find a similar plugin for prototype, or vice-versa. If you are only using prototype for the lightbox, jQuery offers a nice [lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) plugin as well.

Comment: jQuery coda slider is still working even after I replaced "$" with "jQuery". I just can't make them work together.

Comment: check original answer, hope this helps

Comment: That way jQuery is working and Scriptaculous lightbox stops woring. :(

Answer (score 0):

jQuery and Prototype both use the $ selector. noConflict() should fix this conflict but if it isn't you can find the $ signs in your document and replace them with document.getElementById

Answer (score 0):

This is just expanding on Richard Neil Ilagan's point 2 (with which I wholly agree).
In order to work with jQuery in noConflict mode, all plugins should be of the general form:

```
jQuery(function() {
    (function($) {
        $.fn.codaSlider = function() {
            // Plugin's code goes here.     
            // Within this function, $ refers to jQuery.
        };
    })(jQuery);
});
```

The outer function gets executed on page load, and gets access to jQuery without using '$' (so is safe against Prototype).
The inner Self-Executing Function is there merely to create a scope in which $ refers to jQuery.
Inside the SEF, $ refers to jQuery, as is expected by naive plugins that don't support noConflict out-of-the-box. So the code for such a plugin can often be copy'n'pasted into the body of the SEF above, and it will Just Work (tm).

This is superior to changing all instance of '$' to 'jQuery', because it will not change '$' characters in regexes, etc, and leaves the original code unchanged apart from indentation, so easier to merge in future changes.

HTH